# Splitting string with one concatenated LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I wonder if I can transform this:

```
"abc , 123; xyz, 100; go, 9; move, 50;"
```

into this:

```
{ { "abc", "123" } , { "xyz" , "100" } , { "go" , "9" } , { "move" , "50" } }
```

(array of `string[2]`) with one long concatenated `LINQ` statement ?

### Edit:

a `from-in-where-select` statements series is preferred

### Edit 2:

also, is there also a way to transform the input string into some composite type like array of `struct { string, int }` or some `Tuple<string,int>` ?

like:

```
{
    new Tuple<string, int>() { "abc", 123 } ,
    new Tuple<string, int>() { "xyz" , 100 } ,
    new Tuple<string, int>() { "go" , 9 } ,
    new Tuple<string, int>() { "move" , 50 }
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `String.Split` abd `String.Trim` and LINQ `select`.

```
var result = (from keyValuePair in myString.Split(';')
              where keyValuePair.Trim() != ""
              select (from t in keyValuePair.Split(',')
                      select t.Trim()).ToArray()).ToArray();()
```

#### UPDATE

To have an array of `KeyValuePair<string, int>`

```
var result = (from keyValuePair in myString.Split(';')
              where keyValuePair.Trim() != ""
              let splittedKeyValuePair = keyValuePair.Split(',')
              select new KeyValuePair<string, int>(splittedKeyValuePair[0].Trim(), int.Parse(splittedKeyValuePair[1]))).ToArray();
```

To have an `Dictionary<string, int>`

```
var result = (from keyValuePair in myString.Split(';')
              where keyValuePair.Trim() != ""
              select keyValuePair.Split(',')).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp[0].Trim(), kvp => int.Parse(kvp[1]))
```

Comment: Great! is there also a way to transform the input string into this: `{ { "abc", 123 } , { "xyz" , 100 } , { "go" , 9 } , { "move" , 50 } }` ? i.e array of `struct { string, int }` or some `Tuple<string,int>` ?

Comment: @Tal I have updated my post to do this. The result is stored in an array of _KeyValuePair<string, int>_.

Comment: If the strings just before the commas `,` are known to be distinct, it would be natural to create a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string str = "abc , 123; xyz, 100; go, 9; move, 50;";

stringses = str.Split(new[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                        .Select(s => s.Split(new[] {','}))
               .ToArray();
```